# How to convert real pixel values to flutter logical pixel (Density Independent Pixel)

Tags: flutter, dart, ffmpeg

I am using flutter-ffmpeg package to overlay an image onto the video, and after overlay i am drawing a rectangle over that image but the issue is, ffmpeg overlays image using real pixel data and flutter drawing rectangle using logical pixel, so how can i convert real pixel of ffmpeg to logical pixel of flutter so that i can change overlay dimension of image to match with rectangle.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [devicePixelRatio](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Window/devicePixelRatio.html). Here is the definition from Flutter documentation:

> The number of device pixels for each logical pixel. This number might not be a power of two. Indeed, it might not even be an integer. For example, the Nexus 6 has a device pixel ratio of 3.5.
>
> Device pixels are also referred to as physical pixels. Logical pixels
>   are also referred to as device-independent or resolution-independent
>   pixels.

So, `devicePixels / WidgetsBinding.instance.window.devicePixelRatio` should give you logical pixels.